# How can I style highchart select to look like hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

Highcharts is an amazing library, however I need to programatically scroll through the chart as if the cursor itself was hovering across the x-axis. The only way I can think of doing this is by selecting points, unfortunately I could not find options in highcharts api documentation that allows me to put crosshairs/ playheader on selected points.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pawel Fus had a good answer, however I found an even better solution which doesn't have the buggy lag behavior when switching to different time points. Also events are not needed in this solution.

```
           var chart = myElement.highcharts();

           function select(value) {
                    // Scroll to some time.
                    var axes = chart.axes;
                    for (var i = 0; i < axes.length; i ++) {
                        var axis = axes[i];
                        axis.drawCrosshair(null, chart.series[0].points[value])
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                        var series = chart.series[i];

                        // Unset last value
                        series.points[oldValue].setState('');

                        // Set new value
                        series.points[value].setState('hover');
                    }

                    oldValue = value;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not part of the API, but you can use `point.onMouseOver()` to fire mouseover event: http://jsfiddle.net/15dzo23n/1/

Example:

```
var index = 0;
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        events: {
            load: hoverAnim
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true  
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: [5, 10, 15, 12, 13, 14, 12, 1, 12, 1, 12, 12, 12, 1]
    }]
});



function hoverAnim(e) {
    var chart = this,
        points = chart.series[0].points,
        len = points.length;

    if (index < len) {
        chart.hoverSeries = chart.series[0];
        chart.hoverPoint = points[index];
        chart.pointer.runPointActions(e); //display crosshair
        points[index].onMouseOver(e); // display tooltip and set hover state
        index++;
        setTimeout(function () {
            hoverAnim.call(chart, e);
        }, 100);
    }
}
```